# Sending numeric values ​client - server (Socket)

Tags: java

I have a problem sending numerical values ​​from my server to the client. The client socket I keep in an ArrayList, I can connect multiple clients. My for sends random numerical values ​​but until I finish with the socketCliente1 for example continue with the following socketCliente2, if you could help me I would appreciate it very much ...

```
    public void generarNumeroRandom() {
      for (int i = 0; i < arregloNumeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
      int numeroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 25 + 1);
      arregloNumeroAleatorio[i] = numeroAleatorio;
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         if (arregloNumeroAleatorio[i] == arregloNumeroAleatorio[j]) {
              i--;
         }
      }
   }
   }

public void enviarNumeroAleatorioCliente() throws InterruptedException {

generarNumeroRandom();        
for (Socket listaJugadoresConectados : listaJugadores) {
    try {
        DataOutputStream salidaDos = new DataOutputStream(listaJugadoresConectados.getOutputStream());
        for (int i = 0; i < arregloNumeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            salidaDos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(arregloNumeroAleatorio[i]));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HiloServidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: He generates the random numbers and sends them to the client, but for him to pass to the second client I have to wait for him to send all the numbers to the first client and then it goes to the second client, so on. How do I get them to send them at the same time without having to wait, thanks

Comment: You could change the order of your loops, . Or use a thread per socket. That "Thread.sleep" is really going to mess with your results. You really need to make a minimal reproducible example though. "My for sends random " your what? Client or server? What is the code you're showing, the client or the server?